# nav transitioning with css

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a nav-bar and I am trying to make the submenu slide down on hover.

Here is the current CSS I have for the transition:

```css
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    height:150px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
```

However it only does the background of the submenu, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjLS/)

Does anyone know how I would fix this so that the whole menu transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjLS/1/)

I added `overflow:hidden;` and also moved the css transitions to the pre-hover tags.

```
.nav ul ul {
    width: 501px;
    background: #6db6e5;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;    
}
```